# How to import images properly into an array in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file-structure

I have some images in my project folder and want to either use their relative links to show them in each respective array item.

I want to eventually use the image in a react component to show the image on my webpage.

### File Structure

- src

  - assets

    - data

      - project.js
      - projectImages.js
    - images

      - img.jpg
      - img2.jpg
      - img3.jpg
  - components

    - Project.jsx

### Project.jsx

```
export default function Project({ project, theme }) {
  return (
    <div id="project">
      <h3 className="subheading">{project.name}</h3>
      <div>
        <img src={project.img}>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

### project.js

```
// import projectImages from '../data/projectImages' (tried to import an array of img)

module.exports = [
  {
    type: "",
    name: "",
    desc: "",
    tech: ["", "", "", ""],
    summary: "",
    year: ,
    img: '../data/images/img.jpg', // tried projectImages[0]
    link: "",
  },
  {
    ...
    img: '../data/images/img2.jpg', // tried projectImages[1]
    ...
  },
  {
    ...
    img: '../data/images/img3.jpg', // tried projectImages[2]
    ...
  },
```

I have tried to `import img from '../data/projectImages/img.jpg` but the variable was not accepted in the object array.
I have also tried to shove the images into an array and use the array to reference them but that did not work as well.

Comment: I believe you will need a JSON/YAML manifest that lists all the assets by their name, so you can reference their paths dynamically. React does not understand how a directory works like your file system. If this was a Node server, you could list files in the directory, but since React is a client-side application, it cannot know what the system looks like unless you tell it.

Comment: The answer to this depends upon the build system that you are using. `create-react-app`? `vite`? Something else?

Comment: @spender I am using `create-react-app`

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl Could you give me an example of what a JSON manifest would look like in the context of my application? I am having a hard time making sense of the resources online

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl webpack does indeed support [this kind of scenario](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#require-with-expression)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `create-react-app` which uses `webpack` behind the scenes.

It's been a while since I did this, but I believe that you can do something like:

`const myRequireContext = require.context('./someDir', false, /\.jpg$/);`

which will give you an object that looks something like:

```
{
  "./img.jpg": "some/path",
  "./img2.jpg": "some/otherPath",
  "./img3.jpg": "some/yetAnotherPath"
}
```

(this is off-the-top-of-my-head, so details might be a little different)

See https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#require-with-expression

Comment: Thank you this worked! I used `const myRequireContext = require.context('../images', false, /\.jpg$/);` in the top level of my projects.js file and `img: myRequireContext('./img.jpg')` in my object array

Answer (score 0):

Directly inside your array, use require()

```
module.exports = [
  {
    type: "",
    name: "",
    desc: "",
    tech: ["", "", "", ""],
    summary: "",
    year: ,
    img: require('../data/images/img.jpg'), 
    link: "",
  },
  {
    ...
    img: require('../data/images/img2.jpg'), 
    ...
  },
  {
    ...
    img: require("'../data/images/img3.jpg", 
    ...
  },
```